# Setting Friction Dynamically in AndEngine Box2d

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

is there any way to set the friction of a physics body dynamically in (AndEngine Box2D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I think it should work

```
body.getFixtureList().get(0).setFriction(x);
```

In the original Box2D, the friction is cached and you need to call world.Refilter(Shape). There is no such method in the physics extension of AndEngine so I hope it will work. It may not, though.